# Variable disappears next time the function is called?

Tags: javascript, variables, settimeout

My alert does not execute, why!? Shouldn't it appear every 1000 millisecond, after the second time it runs?

```
function MAINGAMELOOP() {
    if (!window.GAMESPEED){
        var GAMESPEED = 1000; 
    } else {
        alert("hi");
    }
    setTimeout(MAINGAMELOOP, GAMESPEED);
}
```

Comment: you're not setting the var in the window's scope. window.GAMESPEED or define it with a 0 value outside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `GAMESPEED = 1000;` you want `window.GAMESPEED = 1000;`.

Comment: Oh man it's just been answered in the comments. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I don't think so, who says that is not forbidden to "copy" other people comments?

Comment: Oh... Of course, Thanks for the help! I've been sitting with this for a long time scratching my head... Thanks!

Comment: @kmoe: Yeah, don't worry about comments. If someone decides to comment instead of answer, that's their concern, not yours. I've deleted my comment. :-)

Comment: Copying a comment is fine. I answer in comments if I don't have time to give a full example.

Answer (score -1):

It's setInterval, not setTimeout. SetTimeout will execute a function once, after the specified delay.